# spring security openid connect request for access token implementation doesn't align cas api requirement

Tags: java, spring-security, openid-connect, cas

I'm working on integrating Spring Security with CAS by openid connect of authorization_code flow. According to openid connect protocol, there are following steps:

1. ....
2. browser get Authentication and code from OpenID Provider
3. browser send the code to client
4. client makes token request to OpenID provider for access token.
5. ....

The issue happened on step 4. Spring Security make the request and put the grant_type, code info into body instead of the url. But CAS require to put the code info into url. [[CAS API for Authorization Code]](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.3.x/installation/OAuth-OpenId-Authentication.html#authorization-code.)

Does anybody has experience with such situation? Any Suggestion is appreciate

Answer (score 1):

You control how the code is delivered to the client using the **response_mode** parameter during the initial authentication request.

It specifies the method that should be used to send the resulting authorization code back to your app. Can be **form_post** or **fragment**. For web applications, we recommend using response_mode=form_post, to ensure the most secure transfer of tokens to your application.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. I just test with response_mode=form_post and the parameter is abandon after redirect by CAS in step 2. So the following steps still act with error in the same way. Please correct me if i make any mistake.

Comment: try set it to form_post=fragment instead, then it will be passed (if supported) in the URL instead of the request body